# Why "read" does not read the first line of a command output?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh, busybox

I want to read the first line of a command output with. but I get an empty message.

I used

```
ls | read line
echo $line #nothing displayed
```

Why the line variable is empty and how to fix that?

The following code works. but I want to read only the first line

```
ls | while read line; do 
    echo $line
done
```

If it's not possible with read, is it possible to do it with other functions like grep, awk, sed ?

Comment: Don't parse `ls`. Use `for line in *; do` to iterate over files.

Answer (score 4):

The `read` does read the first line, but it is being executed in a subshell.  But you can do:

```
ls | { read line; 
  echo $line;
  # other commands using $line;
}
# After the braces, $line is whatever it was before the braces.
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
read line <<< "$(ls)"
printf "%s\n" "$line"
```

But as already mentioned, please, PLEASE, **PLEASE** do not parse `ls` output!